# How should I reproduce this colorful swirling gif?

Tags: graphics, animation, generative-art

Surfing on the web, I came upon this cool GIF:

[image: animation]

Does any one know how to reproduce this in *Mathematica*? I have some ideas myself, so I will try to answer this question as well.

Comment: I saw it yesterday, I should have made it, ah :P

Comment: [This animation is supposed to have music along with it!](http://whitneymusicbox.org/)

Comment: I never messed around with Mathematica's sound functions. It would be cool to see an answer which produces the sounds as well!

Comment: @RahulNarain done :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### [Embedded cdf with music version.](http://byk.oa.uj.edu.pl/%7Ejpodkalicki/shared/CDF/spd.html) *code at the bottom*

---

For full period, change max `t` to `200`, my gif is cut in half because for some reasons I couldn't upload whole.

```
f[r_, t_] := Mod[-t (1 - r), 2. Pi];

dr = Pi /100.

Animate[Graphics[{
   Table[{
          AbsolutePointSize[10 # + 2 + 2 Unitize@Clip[f[#, t] - 5.5, {0, 1}]], 
          Blend[{Blend["Rainbow", #], White}, Clip[f[#, t] - 5.28, {0, 1}]], 
          Point[# {Cos@f[#, t], Sin@f[#, t]}]} &@i,
         {i, 1 - dr, 0, -dr}],
    White, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}, 
   PlotRange -> 1.1, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 300], 
 {t, 0, 100}, AnimationRate -> 5]
```

> [image]

---

#### more processor consuming but working smoothly - version with music:

As Öskå has noticed, it may not work on Linux.

It is not perfectly optimized, I just wonted to do this now and I hope I will have some time and motivation to improve it one day.

```
DynamicModule[{t, f, dt, dr, sound, graf},
 Dynamic[Refresh[
 Column[{
  graf,
  Animator[Dynamic[t, (t = #; With[{sel = Select[sound, t - dt <= #[[1]] <= t &]}, 
   If[Length[sel] != 0, EmitSound@Sound[SoundNote@sel[[1, 2]]]]]) &],
   {0, 200, dt}, AnimationRunning->False, AnimationRate->4, DisplayAllSteps->True]
  }],
   
   None]],
 Initialization :> (
   dt = .2;
   f[r_, t_] := Mod[-t (1 - r), 2 Pi];
   t = 0;
   
   dr = Pi /100;
   
   graf = Graphics[{
      Dynamic@Table[With[{fi = f[i, t]},
         {
          AbsolutePointSize[5 i + 2 + If[fi > 6., 3, 0]], 
          Blend[{Blend["Rainbow", i], White}, Clip[fi - 5.5, {0, 1}]],
          Point[i {Cos@fi, Sin@fi}]}],
        {i, 1 - dr, 0, -dr}],
      White, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]},
     PlotRange -> 1.1, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 300];
   
   sound = Composition[
      
      SortBy[#, First] &,
      {#[[1, 2]], #[[;; , 1]]} & /@ # &,
      GatherBy[#, #[[2]] &] &,
      Flatten[#, 1] &
      
      ]@Table[
      Thread[{(-i + 1)/dr, Range[0, 200, #] &@(2 Pi/(1 - i))}], {i, 
       1 - dr, 0, -dr}];
   )
 ]
```

---

Comment: So you did this at the end ). +1.

Comment: How'd you find the correct expression for the spiral? (Is there a standard expression? I don't know much about spirals...)

Comment: @Pickett The only assumption I've made was to make it linear with `r` since there are rational relations between periods which result with nice configurations like cross or stars.

Comment: @Kuba Ah, I see, thank you. +1 of course.

Comment: And if this won't become a hot network question then I would be *quite* surprised :D

Comment: Nice! Interesting music too. Stockhausen would be proud of you.

Answer (score 9):

Well this is my try, I could work a little bit on the color yet, but I'm pretty happy with it right-now:

```
Animate[
 Show[
  Graphics[
   Transpose[{
    Table[RGBColor[Sqrt[1-r^2], r Sin[θ],r Cos[θ]], {r,0.01,1,0.02}],
    Table[Disk[{r Cos[-2(1-r)θ], r Sin[-2(1-r)θ]},r/60], {r,0.01,1,0.02}]}],
  Background->Black],
 PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1}}, ImageSize->1000],
{θ,0,100π,π/40},DefaultDuration->180]
```

[image]

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for the edit. Do you know how to export gif animations from Mathematica? I could only do it with *.swf format.